# Tensor flow error while trying to print a basic numeric addition

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(x + 5, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
```

This code generates an error saying **Type Error: List of tensors when single tensor expected**

what could be the problem???

*System Details: Virtualbox:Ubuntu 16.04 xenial, tensor flow 0.9.0, python-3.5*

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue --- your code works for me and prints "40". Are you by any chance using an interactive Python environment? If so, perhaps try restarting Python?

Comment: No i am not using interactive Python environment, i am using 'Sublime' as a core editor,apart from that there is nothing different. i have saved the file as 'tensor_test.py' i run it in the terminal using the basic command 'python tensor_test.py' while the tensor source is active.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a conceptual aspect of tensorflow.
First let me start with a code example
    import tensorflow as tf

```
x = tf.constant(35, name='x')
y = tf.Variable(5, name='y')
add = tf.add(x,y)
update = tf.assign(y,add)

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(y))
    print(session.run([add,y]))
    print(session.run([update,y]))
    print(session.run([update,y]))
```

This will print the following

```
5
40 5
40 40
75 75
```

So what is going on?  Firstly, x and y are not 35 and 5.  They are tensorflow objects that contain data and can interact with the tensorflow graph.  x is a constant and will provide the graph with the value of 35 when requested by tensorflow, but it is not equal to 35.  y is a variable that can be assigned a value and updated by tensorflow when it is running.

In you example you set the value of y to be a variable with an initial value of x + 5, but x is not 35.  x is a tensorflow object.

In the example above, we assign the value of 5 to the variable y.  When we run the session and get the value of y, it is 5.  when we get the value of add it is 35+5 but y hasn't changed.  When we execute update we find that the value of y has been updated to 40.  Finally, when we update again we see that y has been incremented again by 35 and is now 75.

I hope this explains the difference between classic python variables and constants and tensorflow variables and constants.